# Android save to file.txt appending

Tags: android, append, filewriter

I admittedly am still learning and would consider myself a novice (at best) regarding programming.  I am having trouble with appending a file in android.  Whenever I save, it will rewrite over the file, and I am having trouble understanding how to keep the file that is already there and only add a new line.  Hoping for some clarity/advice.  Here is how I am saving to the file (which rewrites the file each time I save).

```
public void saveText(View view){

    try {
        //open file for writing
        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("save.txt", MODE_PRIVATE));

        //write information to file
        EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        String text2 = text.getText().toString();
        out.write(text2);
        out.write('\n');

        //close file

        out.close();
        Toast.makeText(this,"Text Saved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } catch (java.io.IOException e) {
        //if caught
        Toast.makeText(this, "Text Could not be added",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change this,

```
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("save.txt", MODE_PRIVATE));
```

to,

```
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("save.txt", Context.MODE_APPEND));
```

This will append your new contents to the already existing file.

I Hope it helps!

Comment: yep.  So, MODE_APPEND was my issue. Thank you very much

Answer (score 8):

Use this method, pass filename and the value to be added in the file

```
public void writeFile(String mValue) {

    try {
        String filename = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath() + mFileName;
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("ENTER_YOUR_FILENAME", true);
        fw.write(mValue + "\n\n");
        fw.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To display the content of the saved file with the line breaks with a button click use:

```
     b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    try {
                        FileInputStream fin = openFileInput(fileTitle);
                        int c;
                        String temp = "";

                        while ((c = fin.read()) != -1) {
                            temp = temp + Character.toString((char) c);
                        }
                        tv.setText(temp);




                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "file read", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            });
```

To Delete content of existing file whist retaining the filename you can use:

```
    deleteOrder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput(fileTitle,MODE_PRIVATE);
           // fOut.write(data.getBytes());
            dataTitle = "";
            fOut.write(data.getBytes());
            fOut.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Takes content of a TextEdit called textTitle. Writes it to file called dataTitle. Then writes a new line with fOut.write("\n"). The next text entered into TextEdit is added to the file with a line break.

```
  try {
                FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput(fileTitle,MODE_APPEND);
                fOut.write(dataTitle.getBytes());
                fOut.write('\n');
                fOut.close();

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"file saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```