# Append to log file doesn't work

Tags: android, logging, java-io, filewriter, file-writing

I try to build a simple android app that shows text on the screen and has a button. I created a log file at the `onCreate()` method and would like to append the new log line to the document upon the click on the button. I used the following code in both `onCreate()` and `onButtonClick()` events:

```
try{
    if(!file.exists()){
        System.out.println("We had to make a new file.");
        file.createNewFile();
    }

    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file, true);

    String ts = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd.HH.mm.ss").format(new Date());
    Log.d("LOGGER" , ts);

    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
    bufferedWriter.write("******* " + ts.toString() +" ******* " + "\n");

    bufferedWriter.close();
    fileWriter.close();

    System.out.println("Done");

} catch(IOException e) {
    System.out.println("COULD NOT LOG!!");
}
```

The file is created and is filled with the data uppon `onCreate()`, the problem is that when I call `onButtonClick()` the new log line is not appended to the log file despite the fact I specified **true** in the `FileWriter` constructor: `new FileWriter(file, true)`.

Could you point me, why my log is not appended with the new lines?

Comment: Show us the code where you attach the listener to the button.

Comment: is the button click function invoked when you click the button?

Comment: I think this link may help you [Append to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625234/how-to-append-text-to-an-existing-file-in-java)

Comment: try this also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27415074/android-save-to-file-txt-appending

Comment: I tried your code but the file is not created...

Comment: I tried to use FileWriter as well as bufferwriter- at the first run it works fine (creating the file, writing to it and append data) but when I want to append data when I push a button (i.e. document the exact time I pushed the data into the file) it does not work...